# I need help adding a like button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

hello looking to ad facebook like to my website.  I am getting an error.  It says...
"the href entered is not recognized as a valid url".  Help!!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was looking for answers on this as well so I'm posting it here so someone else can find it.

you have to enter your entire site name now including the numbers at the end:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/YOURSITE/1212121212 < those numbers. To view them log onto your facebook account and click on your page the copy the link above with the numbers and paste it to the plug in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL for the link button includes the http / https part. Also, the like button code should have the `data-href` attribute in it. Finally, run your URL through the [Facebook Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and check that your page doesn't have any issues.